# How to correctly pass a whole array (not its items) as a parameter? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a set of divs that I store in an array that I then need to through and perform an action on everything *except* for the current iterated value. I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a03kjwfy/), which I think explains my situation properly.

Here is the function I'm using to select everything *except* for the value of (in this case) `n`.

```
const getRestOfArray = (array, n) => {
    let arrayCopy = array.slice();
    let index = arrayCopy.indexOf(n);
    if (index > -1) {
        arrayCopy.splice(index, 1);
        return arrayCopy;
    }
};
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: what's the problem? your function returns either the new array if n is found, or undefined if it is not - is that what you expected?

Comment: I have the expected result commented in the fiddle. I need it to not return undefined for an array of divs.

Comment: then return something - up to you what you return as I haven't even gone to the fiddle as your problem should be defined and described on SO, not some external site

Comment: What is the desired return value if the passed in value is not found?  Whatever that desired return value, you just need to return that when your `if` statement doesn't match.  I don't understand what you're asking for help with.

Comment: The only time there is an `.indexOf(2)` is in your array of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.indexOf()` is not necessary. `2` is not an element of either array containing letters or `DOM` elements. You can call `.splice()` with `n` as first parameter, `1` as second parameter to return expected result.

```
const getRestOfArray = (array, n) => {
  let arrayCopy = array.slice();
  arrayCopy.splice(n, 1);
  return arrayCopy;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a03kjwfy/1/

Comment: @Shanling You could alternatively use `.slice()`, `.concat()`;  `const getRestOfArray = (array, n) => array.slice(0, n).concat(array.slice(n + 1, array.length))` https://jsfiddle.net/a03kjwfy/3/

Comment: perfect, works like a charm. thank you! I knew I was doing something incorrectly.. think I misunderstood how indexOf() worked. thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just return the array copy if the index is not in the array, like so

```
const getRestOfArray = (array, n) => {
    let arrayCopy = array.slice();
    let index = arrayCopy.indexOf(n);
    if (index > -1) {
        arrayCopy.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return arrayCopy;
};
```